# Bitbucket Pipeline automatic running black before the commit when pull request merged

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, python-black

I am trying to set up Bitbucket Pipeline to auto-format my python codebase. All I'm doing is running black.

I'm working with distributed dev teams and it's hard to get everyone to install pre-commit hooks on their local machine so for now I just want to run black whenever code is merged. I don't want this to be a check that fails the merge.

My expectation is that whenever a commit is made to `master` branch (so whenever pull request is merged), black would be run auto-format the code AND THEN the commit is made. I am also not worried about only running black on affected files, for now I just want to run black against the whole codebase.

Anyway, with my current setup, my testing shows that black is run *after* the commit and not before.

here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```yaml
image: python:3.10

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: run black
          script:
            - pip install black
            - black -l 88 .
```

Comment: Yes, pipeline is ran and cannot reverse the commit. You can setup a condition that the build must succeed before the pull request(s) are allowed to be merged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after much figuring out, I figured out a way. I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works. I've changed the goal for the Bitbucket Pipeline to beautify the code and commit the reformatted code whenever a pull request is created or updated instead.

This solution is inspired by:

- ["Automating pull request creation from one branch to another using javascript, bitbucket pipelines and bitbucket api" by Benedict Steven](https://dev.to/clickpesa/automating-pull-request-creation-from-one-branch-to-another-using-javascript-bitbucket-pipelines-and-bitbucket-api-3ijh)
- ["GitHub Actions: How to Automate Code Formatting in Pull Requests" by Peter Evans](https://peterevans.dev/posts/github-actions-how-to-automate-code-formatting-in-pull-requests/)

### Step 1: Create an OAuth2 Consumer

1. Go to **"Workspace Settings"**
2. Under category **"Apps and Features"**, click **"OAuth consumers"**
3. Click **"Add consumer"**, fill out necessary information. Makes sure to add permission to **"read"** and **"write"** for **Pull Requests** permission category. Also,  **"Callback URL"** can't be empty, I used https://google.com .
4. Click **"Save"**
5. Your new OAuth consumer will have a *Key* and *Secret* generated
   [image: Adding OAuth Consumer on Bitbucket]

### Step 2: Configure the Bitbucket Respository

1. Go to the repository that will have the Bitbucket Pipeline setup
2. Click **"Repository settings"**
3. Under category **"Pipelines"**, click **"Repository variables"**
4. Add a new variable with *name* being `BB_AUTH_STRING` and *value* being a string of format `Key:Secret` (see picture), using the key and secret of the OAuth consumer we created earlier
5. Make sure to fill the checkbox **"Secured"** before clicking **"Add"**
   [image: Adding Repository variable using the key and secret of the OAuth Consumer]

### Step 3: Setup your Bitbucket Pipeline YML

The `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` I've settled on currently is the following:

```yaml
image: python:3.10

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step:
          name: Commit if there are changed files
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -y install curl jq
            - pip install black
            - black -l 100 .
            - modified=$(if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then echo "false"; else echo "true"; fi)
            # BB_AUTH_STRING is a "Repository Variable", 
            # it's value is a string of the format "Key:Secret"
            # with "Key" and "Secret" being the key and secret of a OAuth2 Workspace Consumer
            - >
              if [ "$modified" = "false" ]; then 
                exit 0; 
              else
                export BB_TOKEN=$(curl -s -S -f -X POST -u "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" \
                https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
                -d grant_type=client_credentials -d scopes="repository" | jq --raw-output '.access_token') ;
                git config --global user.name 'Automatic Linter';
                git config --global user.email 'techs@domain.com';
                git remote set-url origin "https://x-token-auth:${BB_TOKEN}@bitbucket.org/vietthan/myrepositoryname.git";
                git add -A;
                git commit -m "[skip ci] automatic linter";
                git push;
              fi

          condition:
            changesets:
              includePaths:
                - "**"
```

This pipeline will only run whenever a Pull-Request is created and whenever new commits are made to the Pull Request.

The pipeline will install `curl` and `jq`.

The pipeline will install `black`.

The pipeline will then run `black -l 100`.

If no files were modified, the pipeline will exit.

Else:

1. It will use `BB_AUTH_STRING` to get a temporary access token stored in `BB_TOKEN`.
2. It will set the git configuration for name, email
3. It will set the git remote path+access token, I have this pointed to my intending repository.
4. It will add all changed files, make a commit with `[skip ci]` in the commit head message to skip the pipeline when this commit is push
5. Push the commit

### Conclusion

You now have a bitbucket pipeline that will automatically format Python code with `black` whenever your developers create a pull request or push new commits to it. It will avoid infinite bitbucket pipeline builds, it will detect if there are changes before committing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a change in feature set, but it appears there is an easy way to do this documented at https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/push-back-to-your-repository/. Simply `git commit` and `git push`. 
However it also notes if you have branch permissions or want to commit with a "bot" accoutn you need to use OAuth. It also documents an SSH Key pair option.

Comment: Lol, looks like this has been around since at least 2020. Maybe I needed the right keywords.